# Avoid duplicates on a view based on results from another view

Tags: views

I have a node type and two views:

- One displaying the last 3 elements with a field marked as «important».
- Another with 3 random elements, marked as important or not.

I don't want the views to repeat nodes.

Since the "lasts" views should always display the last 3 important elements, I thought about filtering the nodes on the random view, but I don't know how.

I managed to do it for a single node in another context. When viewing a node, choosing «Provide default value» with some PHP code combined with the option «Exclude», I can manage to hide that node from the views.

```
$node = menu_get_object();

if (isset($node->nid)) {
   return $node->nid;
}
else{
  return 0;
}
```

Suppose I can get the nodes shown on the "lasts" views programatically. Then what? This approach will only work to filter out a single node, not the three I'll get from that view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the contextual filters, there's an option called «Allow multiple values» just above «Exclude». That option lets you return multiple values separated by commas (and) or mores (or).

So, I just use this code in the «Provide default value» field:

```
$my_view_name = 'videos';
$my_display_name = 'otros_importantes';

$my_view = views_get_view_result($my_view_name, $my_display_name);
if ( $my_view!=null ) {
  foreach($my_view as $view_row){
    $nodos[]=$view_row->nid;
  }
}

if(isset($nodos)){
  return implode(",",$nodos);
}
else{
  return 0;
}
```

And that's all, the nodes shown on that display are ignored.